# Block Diagram Algebra - Sine Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

What is the transfer function of a system which computes the sine of its input (i.e. with input = $\theta$, output = $\sin (\theta)$?)

We have only been using linear systems so far in class.

Comment: I think you want the Taylor expansion of sine or some other algorithm to compute sine.

Comment: A transfer function is a ratio of output/input, and in a linear system, is independent of input and output.  Is this case, the transfer function, for lack of a better word, is $\sin{x}/x$, where $x$ is the input to the system.

Comment: @rlgordonma So the transfer function is the Laplace transform (I'm using Laplace here) of the sinc function? which is arctan (1/s)

Comment: No, I don't think so, because the LT (or the Fourier transform) assume linearity.